# Array of strings randomly remove 3 and replace with “” but keep original indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
    const state = reactive({    
      verify: [
        "brain",
        "show",
        "toy",
        "him",
        "aim",
        "built",
        "store",
        "there",
        "skim",
        "wing",
        "honest",
        "try",
      ],
    });

function remove(array: string[], numberOfDeletions: number) {
  array = state.array;
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDeletions; i++) {
    array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length), 1);
  }
  console.log(array);
}
onMounted(async () => {
  const mnemonic = await removeRandomly(state.verify, 3);
});
function getWords(words: Array<string>) {
  state.mnemonicPhrase = words;
}
```

this is removing 3 items  and being replaced with "" but the changed indexes are being  pushed to the last 3 indexes i need everything to stay in its original indexes and i cant seem to figure out whats going on here

also note that i have a ternary in my Vue code to change the value of props if the input is empty to return "" so i can visually see it is working that its being removed

Comment: I don't see any replacement going on. Did you mean to perhaps use `array.splice(randomIndex, 1, "")`? FYI, your random number generator has a chance to attempt removing the same index multiple times

Comment: What exactly you are looking for doesn't look all clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
 for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDeletions; i++) {
    arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length), 1,"");
  }
```